# Executing a function on multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to splice the work on multiple threads using ThreadPooling. I wanna use every available thread to assign (and calculate in a different part of the program down the line) the output of an array member to another array members.

It does work, but it is much slower than just adding them on a single thread. Is my usage wrong or is this operation too simple for multithreading?

arrayI and arrayX variables are in classScope, i couldnt pass them as QueueUserWorkItem argument without converting them in setNeuronInput.

```
if (layerType != 0)
        {
            for (arrayI = 0; arrayI < layerSize -1 ; arrayI++)
            {
                for (arrayX = 0; arrayX < network.Layers[layerIndex - 1].layerSize - 1; arrayX++)
                {
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(setNeuronInput), null);

                    //Neurons[i].input[x] = _network.Layers[layerIndex - 1].Neurons[x].output;
                }

            }
        }

        //ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out availableThreads, out placeHolder);
        //while (availableThreads != maxThreads)
        //{
        //    ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out availableThreads, out placeHolder);
        //}
        //return;

    }



    public void setNeuronInput(object o)
    {
        try
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Thread is working");
            Neurons[arrayI].input[arrayX] = network.Layers[layerIndex - 1].Neurons[arrayX].output;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            Console.WriteLine("ArrayI is : " + arrayI);
            Console.WriteLine("ArrayX is : " + arrayX);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Parallel.For`/`Parallel.ForEach` do the same as what you are trying to achieve. Is there a reason you're not using them?

Comment: Consider using Parallel LINQ's `.AsParallel()` or the TPL's `Parallel.For` and `Parallel.ForEach` instead of rolling your own. Aside from that, *individual array assignments* are way too small to parallelize effectively. You want to look at parallelizing big blocks. And if you're looking to doing things with neural nets, consider libraries like [ML.NET](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/apps/machine-learning-and-ai/ml-dotnet) instead of rolling your own, unless this is entirely for learning purposes and you don't care about performance.

Comment: Please add your metrics and way of measuring to the question

Comment: I havent heard of Parallel.For/ForEach, I'll look into them. And I will use it for parallelizing more complex calculations down the line, but i wanted to see if i can do it in this simple exapmle. And my tutor wanted me to build a neural network system without libraries, so thats why i got stuck. For performance, for MNIST dataset for 60k images, it took 5.56 secs to process %15 of the dataset sequantially, but it tooks 20+ secs to process %5,6133 of the dataset with the code above.

Comment: Adding a whole bunch of threads can slow things down (remember, a single CPU core can only execute one thing at a time (for some definition of "one thing")).  Parallel.For/Foreach will hand work off to threads in the thread pool in a way that roughly maximizes thread throughput.  If you do any I/O (or similar) operations in the work you are doing in each thread, be sure to do it asynchronously, and consider using async/await to prevent your threads from hanging.